# Pyinstaller error " 'os' has no attribute "

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.9

I'm trying to create an executable file (python3), until now it had always worked fine (but I never really bothered with pyinstaller).

Now I get this error message (the module "os" I had already in other programs where it had worked)

```
64 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.1
64 INFO: Python: 3.9.2
69 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.10.0-15-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
70 INFO: wrote /root/BUILD/stat.spec
75 INFO: UPX is not available.
76 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/root/BUILD']
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 79, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "/root/BUILD/stat.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib, ssl, sys, mysql.connector, psutil, statistics, base64
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 44, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I use these modules in the script

```
import smtplib, ssl, sys, mysql.connector, psutil, statistics, base64
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

Comment: Do you have a module in your code called `stat.py`?

Comment: stat.py is the script I want to compile.

Comment: Changed my question, I use these modules ️

Comment: You can't give a script the same name as a standard module.  You can see in the traceback that `os` tried to do `import stat`.  When it did so, it loaded YOUR stat.  Choose a different file name.